# Should we follow http method verb specification while creating restful class methods

Tags: rest, web-services

I come across this question many times that Rest by principle does not impose any restriction on the http verbs used on the methods .i.e I can still use a http post (@Post) to fetch a resource.

What would be the side effect on such an implementation?

Comment: I doubt that anybody claims an API based only on `POST` to be RESTful. `POST` is not idempotent, for example.

Answer (score 0):

It will have semantic impact basically, to read a resource  GET should be used and to Create/Update PUT/POST should be used.

GET doesn't effect the resource on server means not creating updating its just a read, whereas POST/PUT effect the resource on server it is created or updated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are mentioning "class methods". When talking about RESTful APIs, the methods in your classes are an implementation detail that should have nothing to do with the RESTful API you are designing. You could choose a design where methods at a class level closely relate to actions your RESTful API provides, but you don't have to. The important part here is that both are conceptually on different layers.

Second, you should absolutely *not* design your RESTful API in a way that enables clients to fetch resources via the HTTP `POST` method. While there's technically nothing that prevents you from doing so, it directly contradicts the spirit of what RESTful APIs are all about.